# Take an Active Window screenshot on OSX

Tags: macos, window

I want to be able to take screenshots of background applications while 1) making them appear active, and 2) not brining them to the foreground. Background windows have icons and title bars greyed out which is not ideal for taking a picture of your app.

I've been using SonOfGrab (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) to capture screenshots, but it always shows all background applications as inactive (buttons, titlebar, etc. all greyed out).

Is there such a message that paints the window as active, but does not move it into the foreground?

For example here's an active Word:
[image]

Here's Word captured from Son of Grab:
[image]

Notice how all toolbar icons and title bar are no longer active. Looking to fix SonOfGrab to make these appear active, but without bringing the window to the foreground.

Answer (score -1):

When a Windowed Application has the focus, it's immediately moved into the foreground.

You can make your app be like when it's in the foreground (design), but the "focus" can be given only once.

Comment: Icons and title bar grey out when the application is not in focus. I want to trick it into appearing in focus but while it is not in focus.

Comment: Are you able to change window "design" ? If you are, you can set 2 "design mode" : automatic when the window has focus, and "focus-like" when it has not focus

Comment: these are any desktop apps, so ones I didn't write. Is there an api for what you described?

Comment: Oh, you wanna make like : i am in iTunes app, so, with focus, and your app is in a background process, but looks like focused too ?

Comment: I don't know if there is an API for what I said but sure, there is a way to do this. I'm not on computer i cant search

Comment: Yeah, updated my question to be more specific: looking to take screenshots of applications. I want my app to be in the foreground and allow you to take screenshots of any background application. Problem is all the screens are coming back inactive which I think would be a bad user experience.

Answer (score -1):

To take screenshots of apps looking active, run and keep your app in the foreground, like iTunes does with its "Mini Player" :
[image: iTunes Mini-Player]

Take a look at [setLevel: in NSWindow Class' Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setLevel:).

You can use [these values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Window_Levels) in argument.

i.e, iTunes uses a thing like

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)))
```

but, if you don't use swift, take a look on the links I gave and make some tests depending on what you want.

Then, run your app, open the app you wanna take a screenshot, and both will looks like "in the foreground".

Comment: This requires moving the application into the foreground. I want to keep the desktop as is and not disturb keyboard focus.

Comment: Your app will still get its keyboard shortcut but not keyboard input, the screenshotted app will have focus. It allowed things like "capture" (i dont know the english for this app) by apple. You should have it on your mac, it's the native screen-saver app

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid ?

Comment: I want my application to run in the background and periodically monitor application visual changes. Not spyware. The user will know its there. It would be very annoying to bring a window to foreground every few seconds.

Comment: I don't understand at all. I didnt explain how to make a spyware. If you find an application that do with its windows what you want to do, please notify me

Comment: Sorry, meant that my software will need to run in the background, and wanted to emphasize that my software will not by spyware (since it'll be taking screenshots from the background) and that the user would know its there.

Answer (score -1):

Press Cmd + Shift + 4, then press space, and select the window you'd like to use.

Cheers!